# pass variables from controller to view in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

how to i pass variables from a controller to a view (tpl) file in OpenCart?

i have coded a custom module so i need to pass the the returned status to the view.

below is a part of my controller where i load the tpl (its a  huge function, i have copied only the required block)

```
$message = '';

if (isset($_POST['server_response'])) {
$message .= 'Server Says= ' . $_POST['server_response'] . "\n";
}

if (isset($_POST['output'])) {
$message .= 'Output= ' . $_POST['output'] . "\n";

    $this->data['msg'] = $message;

$this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success');

                if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/success.tpl')) {
                    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/success.tpl';
                } else {
                    $this->template = 'default/template/payment/success.tpl';
                }

                $this->children = array(  
                    'common/column_left',
                    'common/column_right',
                    'common/content_top',
                    'common/content_bottom',
                    'common/footer',
                    'common/header'
                );

                $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
}
```

in my success.tpl when i `echo $msg` it says:

> Notice: Undefined variable: msg in
>   C:\wamp\www\site\catalog\view\theme\hype\template\payment\success.tpl
>   on line 16

can someone tell how can i pass the $msg variable from the controller to the tpl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

Try setting the variable outside of any of your if statements to a default value eg.

```
$this->data['msg'] = 'test';
```

To make sure that it's not any of the other logic such as the

```
$_POST['output']
```

that is faulty.

At the moment you just set $message outside the if statement.

When the if statement doesn't evaluate to true $this->data['msg'] will never get set.

Answer (score 2):

You can use for open cart 1.4x and 1.5x

```
$this->data['variableName'] = 'value';
```

but for latest open cart version 2.0x things are changed. Now you can use

```
$data['variableName'] = 'value';
```

Answer (score 0):

How to work with controller variables and various other details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13484904/711273) here. You basically use

```
$this->data['msg'] = 'your value';
```

in the controller, which gets extracted to `$msg` in the template file

You should also note that using `$_POST` instead of the framework's proper method of `$this->request->post` is frowned upon and should be changed accordingly